# Delete row of MySQL database with $_GET parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, get

So I have a table named recept_felhasznalok_pending with four columns one of which is email. I want to be able to delete a row from the table using a link I can send anyone. I have the following PHP code in deny.php:

```
<?php
include('database.php');

///////////////////////////////////

function azonositott_e() {
    return ($_SESSION["email"] === "This is the email address of the person I want to be able to use the link.");
}    
session_start();
if (!azonositott_e()) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}

function db($kapcsolat, $email) {
    $torol = vegrehajtas($kapcsolat,
        "DELETE FROM `recept_felhasznalok_pending` WHERE `email` = :email",
        [ ":email" => $email ]
    );
}

if ($_GET['email']) {
    db($kapcsolat, $_GET['email']);
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

The database.php file has the connection and execute parts of the code:

```
<?php
function kapcsolodas($kapcsolati_szoveg, $felhasznalonev = '', $jelszo = '') {
  $pdo = new PDO($kapcsolati_szoveg, $felhasznalonev, $jelszo);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  return $pdo;
}

function lekerdezes($kapcsolat, $sql, $parameterek = []) {
  $stmt = $kapcsolat->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($parameterek);
  return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

function vegrehajtas($kapcsolat, $sql, $parameterek = []) {
  return $kapcsolat
    ->prepare($sql)
    ->execute($parameterek);
}

$kapcsolat = kapcsolodas(
  'mysql:host=*********;dbname=************;charset=utf8',
  '********', '***********');
?>
```

When I open domain.com/deny.php?email=example@example.com (logged in) that row should be deleted from the table, but it doesn't, I just get redirected to index.php. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: There is no mistake in database.php as it works everywhere else in my project. Also, I don't get any error messages.

Comment: Try DELETE FROM recept_felhasznalok_pending WHERE email = ':email'

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: @Squareoot there should not be quotes around a placeholder. What they have now is what they should use.

Comment: Firstly its very bad idea to do database operation from get params. Its not recomended at all. If you want to proceed also please sanitize the get input.

Comment: This is just for testing, I just can't make it work.

Comment: @CoderSam theOP uses prepared statements, so there is no risk of sql injection.

Comment: And it is not a problem with the get params, because when I hard code the email that I want to delete, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TamasKoos there is no php error handling in the code, this way it is difficult to get any error message.

Comment: See prepared statements are also not immune from attack.

Comment: Where is the bindParam directive in database.php function vegrehajtas

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but that funtcion works everywhere else where I call it, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: @CoderSam the parameters are passed directly to the execute() method.

Comment: @TamasKoos there is nothing obviously wrong with your code. I'm afraid if you do not do some proper debugging and give us some lead as to what could have gone wrong, we are not likely to be able to help you.

Comment: It's very unusual to want to delete data - especially from a get. More usually, one would have a flag to identify 'hidden' or 'deleted' rows

Comment: If you are not recieving error then please check the privelege of the sql user. Does delete operation is granted to him?